# Show the URL parameter in a title

Tags: php, wordpress, url, split, referer

My URL `www.exemple.com/?cl=client1`, `www.exemple.com/?cl=client2`, `www.exemple.com/?cl=client3`,  I want to put the URL parameter in the body of the site, presenting the parameter as follows: "client1", "client2", "client3"

How can I put this in the header of my site made in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the predefined PHP variable `$_GET` like so:

`<?php
// save the URL parameter into a variable
$client = htmlspecialchars($_GET['cl']);
// print the variable contents on the page
echo 'Hello ' . $client . '!';
?>`

It "gets" the URL parameters and saves them in an associative array.

So, `$client = $_GET["cl"];` is gonna give you what you're looking for.

And passing it through `htmlspecialchars` converts special characters to HTML entities which you should always do when grabbing content from a URL.

Reference: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I put the code you said in an html and nothing happened :(

Comment: I just modified the code in my answer. This should work now. You first need to save the URL parameter into a variable and then you can use it for printing on a page.

Comment: I've pasted the code into an html element of the plugin gravity forms and nothing

Comment: Are you actually visiting a URL that ends with `?cl=client1` or not? That code is currently looking for `?cl=something` at the end of the URL. So, if you don't have a `?cl=` in the URL, you'll only see "Hello !" displayed on the page. Do you see that?

Comment: If that part of the plugin where you pasted the code isn't outputting any HTML, then you wouldn't see anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm opening the url correctly. How can I show you my backoffice?

Comment: What do you see on the page where the code is expected to show output? Do you see just "Hello !" or do you see nothing at all?

Comment: I do not see anything! contact me on www.rubenlascasas.com

Comment: I'm not gonna contact you anywhere outside this website. You might want to study how this website here works and why people take their free time to answer other people's questions here. 
Now, if you don't see anything there, then the problem is *not* my code. The problem, in this case, is: You put my code somewhere where it's not going to generate any visible output. OR... maybe there are some css rules that make the output invisible. In any case, the problem is not with my code but with your placement of my code inside the PHP file where you put it. That's where you need to investigate.

Comment: And by the way, I had actually tested my code (i.e. the corrected version). It works.